# Java: Create Instances based on prototype

Tags: java, prototype, instantiation, cloning

How can I, and What is the best/proper way (ie, most performant and clearest syntactically) in Java to create object instances based on a prototype object instance, when this will occur repeatedly and in a performance critical code path?

I have thought about cloning via a cloning support library, but is that the best/only way?  (These need to be arbitrary objects, btw, not ones that implement Clonable).

To clarify what I mean: I have an existing instance of Class T, which has fields set on it, and I want to pop out many versions of the same object to use separately, with the best performance and syntactic clarity possible.

Thanks.

Comment: `new T(prototypeT)`? `prototypeT.copy()`?

Comment: what do you mean by "best way" ?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker I tried to make that clear with "best performance and syntactic clarity"

Comment: @JBNizet Except it requires the classes to support the prototype constructor, which I don't want to require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a builder, which receives this class instance:

```
Person newOne = new PersonBuidler(oldOne).setAge(42)
```

Implementation of this builder may use apache common BeanUtils for cloning Java Beans or some other utility library for cloning arbitrary class.
See [How do I copy an object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java)